Is it necessary that centre of gravity always coincident with geometrical Centroid for 4 point particle?
see the figure:

The cross quadrilateral (also known as a butterfly quadrilateral) has a centroid that appears outside when drawn using GeoGebra. However, when equal masses are placed at points A, B, C, and D, why doesn't the center of gravity of these four masses coincide with the centroid of the quadrilateral?"

The centroid or geometric mean of a shape is usually defined by
$$ \vec x_\text{mean} := \frac{1}{\mathcal N}\int_\text{shape} \vec x\, d \mu$$
in your case, the shape is twisted. GeoGebra most likely interprets the left triangle as negatively oriented. Therefore, the area is counted negatively.
$$ \vec x_\text{mean} := \frac{1}{\mathcal N}\int_\text{shape} \sigma \vec x\,, d\mu$$
where $\sigma = \pm 1$ depending on the orientation. And the normalization is $\mathcal N = \int_\text{shape} \sigma \, d\mu$

How do I confirm that geogebra is taking the left triangle as negatively orientated and also is it possible to remove it?

Ideally, this should be part of the documentation. But apparently it is not.
